# Usefulness of Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()

Tags: java, android, gradle, import, version

I am importing an old project with the latest version of Android (Android Studio 4).

Gradle is at version 1.3.0 and therefore I get the error `Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix ()`. I know how to resolve this error, but I don't know what it is, what does it change if I don't resolve this error?

Regarding the organization of the "Android" view for the project, it is not displayed correctly when I do not resolve the error but it is formatted well when I resolve the error. My wish is to have the "Android" view in good shape (like when creating a new project) because currently, the "Android" view is similar to the "Project" view.

The problem when I resolve the `Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix ()` error is that it causes a lot of successive errors. That's why I just want to know what this method is for and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Android Studio 3.0.1, I fixed the issue with the following two steps. Step 1: Change Gradle plugin version in project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {

        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()

        maven {

            url 'https://maven.google.com/'

            name 'Google'

        }

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }

}
```

Step 2: Change Gradle version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: i followed the same procedure, and it works but i don't want to update gradle and wanted to know what this is doing for the project or if i have to update gradle. The errors also don't show up, for example I called a method that doesn't exist in a class and the method doesn't highlight in red. This problem is surely related.

Comment: i ended up using your version of gradle and it causes a lot less errors, thank you! However, I still want to know what this error is and what it causes if it is not resolved?